# Word VBA - Replacing ActiveDocument.Path

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a lot of links in the document and am trying to write a code to replace all ActiveDocument.Path with a certain word. However, the following code does not seem to recognize ActiveDocument.Path as an input. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ActiveDocument.Path
    .Replacement.Text = "xxx"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAl
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Word you are using. Please make sure to save the docuemnt. What is happening? Try `MsgBox ActiveDocument.Path` and check with manual finding.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? How has the document's path been inserted into the document? Has it been typed (and if so, has the document been moved/copied) ? Or has it been inserted using a  { FILENAME } field code, in which case, is the field code still there, or what?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "the following code does not seem to recognize ActiveDocument.Path as an input".  It's not clear at all how this is "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert the activedocument.path to your document and then check manually what is wrong with the actual text.
run this to see the actual path and then if it is showing OK, rest is easy.

```
Sub test()
ActiveDocument.Range.Collapse wdCollapseStart
ActiveDocument.Range.InsertBefore ActiveDocument.Path
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your code shows the actual path. I am using Word 2013.

Comment: While searching manually after inserting the path, does it finds the text you are after. Please provide the actual link that you are trying to show. Please check the path separator as it may be different. If what you want to replace is a hyperlink and not the text, then there is different way of searching for that.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. The path separator was different. Now everything is working fine.